# Tooblar MenuItem Visibility issue in Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am using Appcompat toolbar, which has one MenuItem with custom action view in Activity. When I switch to fragment I have separate toolbar and I don't want activity MenuItem to be displayed in fragment hence I am setting it's visibility to false.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
    menuItem.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

So far it is works fine.

But when I go back to activity same MenuItem is not visible. Here is how I am making it visible again. onCreateOptionsMenu is getting called as I am invalidating a menu in onResume() but MenuItem is not visible.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_actionbar_actions, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
    menuItem.setVisible(true).setEnabled(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the different menu in fragment :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

If you want to hide menu in fragment just use `setHasOptionsMenu(false)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

When you say switch to fragment are you switching fragments on same Activity? If so, best approach would be to delete menu code from Activity and implement it in Fragment so that you can control menu at Fragment level.

Comment: Activity has some default dashboard to show and has it's own MenuItem. In fragment setHasOptionMenu is set to false but it still shows same MenuItem which is there in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Javadocs says:

> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
>
> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
>   displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)

So, if you just hiding fragment, activity will not be recreated (but it is not clear, what is "switching" from activity and fragments, fragments can not be shown without activity), so this function "onCreateOptionsMenu" will not called again.

The easiest way is to save MenuItem as a member variable in activity and have methods "showMenu/hideMenu". And call them, when you change fragments.

Comment: onCreateOptionMenu can be called if you invalidate the menu which is anyway happening.  My problem is while coming back on activity onCreateOptionMenu is getting called but still menuitem is not visible. For clarity I am editing the question too.

Comment: Are you going back from different activity? How did you check onCreateOptionMenu is getting called?